# Substraction of records depending upon two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

table1- testquestion

```
| ID |       QUESTION | ANSWER | STATUS |
-----------------------------------------
|  1 | first question |  demo1 |   done |
|  2 |    second que. |  demo2 |   done |
|  3 |      Third que |  demo3 |   done |
|  4 |     Fourth que |  demo4 |   done |
```

Table2- Playedby

```
| ID | PLAY_ID | QUEST_ID | PLAYER_ANSWER |
-------------------------------------------
|  1 |       5 |        1 |             c |
|  2 |       4 |        1 |             a |
|  3 |       5 |        2 |             d |
|  4 |       4 |        2 |             b |
|  5 |       4 |        3 |             b |
|  6 |       4 |        4 |             c |
|  7 |       1 |        1 |             a |
|  8 |       3 |        1 |             c |
|  9 |       1 |        3 |             d |
```

I want to fetch those question who not played by user. for Example Taking user 1.
I want to fetch the question who not played by user 1. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Try `LEFT JOIN` like this:

```
   SELECT q.*
     FROM testquestion q
LEFT JOIN Playedby p
       ON q.id = p.quest_id
      AND play_id = 1
    WHERE p.play_ID IS NULL
```

Output (for `Play_id = 1`)

```
╔════╦═════════════╦════════╦════════╗
║ ID ║  QUESTION   ║ ANSWER ║ STATUS ║
╠════╬═════════════╬════════╬════════╣
║  2 ║ second que. ║ demo2  ║ done   ║
║  4 ║ Fourth que  ║ demo4  ║ done   ║
╚════╩═════════════╩════════╩════════╝
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e33db/12)

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this outputs the questions that the player has answered. But I'm thinking the OP wants to know which questions the player has not answered yet?

Comment: @JensWegar - IMO `PLAY_ID` means Player ID. and `PLAYER_ANSWER` means the answer of the question.